# minDate function dont work correctly in date picker with time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, timepicker

I using date & time picker but don't work bellow function correctly.

I guess the time picker minDate function jQuery UI have conflict with time picker

I'm change the location script and delete minDate functions in time picker but doesn't work correctly

```
 jQuery('.datepicker1').datetimepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      jQuery('.datepicker2').datetimepicker({
          minDate: new JalaliDate(inst['selectedYear'], inst['selectedMonth'], inst['selectedDay']),
      });
  },
});
```

can u help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
    jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({minDate:"+0d",onSelect:function(tarih){
        jQuery("#datepicker2").datepicker("destroy");
        var myDate = new Date(tarih)
        myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1)
        tarih = myDate.getFullYear().toString() + "/"
        tarih += (myDate.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "/"
        tarih += myDate.getDate().toString() 
        jQuery("#datepicker2").datepicker({minDate:tarih}).delay(100).val(tarih);
   }});
```

Comment: thank yo.I use dateTimepicker.not working minDate function at all